# Minimum APIs for Linux

Tags: linux, posix, development, api

It seems that the Linux kernel (All POSIX OSs?) contains only 300+ system calls. Does this mean that any OS implementing those APIs (directly or by translation tables) can run software written for Linux (e.g. Firefox)?

If not - what *is* needed besides that?

Yes, this is a very basic question on a topic I'm only starting out with (OS design). Apparently it's [not accepted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39228578/minimum-apis-for-linux), and I was directed here instead. If it's not - please let me know. (And if so, if you know where it *does* belong, I'll be happy to hear.)

Comment: Side note here : Linux is _not_ POSIX-compliant. It is close, but not quite : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX#Mostly_POSIX-compliant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A minimal implementation of Linux's system calls doesn't mean that an application will run correctly.  There's much to the semantics of the calls that Linux applications may assume:

- Linux-specific `ioctl` and `fcntl` values
- Linux-specific virtual files in `/sys`, `/proc`, etc.
- Presence of standard programs in `/bin` and elsewhere
- Semantics of running processes such as the `init` process and (in some cases) DBus etc.